# Multiple displays + Unity

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Unity work in multi-monitor configurations?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9886/how-does-unity-work-in-multi-monitor-configurations)

I was wondering how Unity looks and functions with 2 or 3 monitors running at the same time.

Can the main bar be moved to the top or bottom of the screen? Having it just at the left of the middle screen would be atrocious.

I run 3 monitors currently, but don't have access to Unity at the moment. Can anyone give me an idea or post a screenshot of how it appears?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How does Unity work in multi-monitor configurations?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9886/how-does-unity-work-in-multi-monitor-configurations/)
https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/661450

Check that out!

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't find that question and it didn't recommend any to me when creating this one. Subscribing to this bug report.
Don't want my triple monitor setup looking awful.

Comment: If the question is in fact a duplicate instead of posting the link to the question as an answer (because it's *really* not an "answer") Either drop a comment or flag the question to be closed as duplicate