# Will the new Unity support dual monitors better then what Gnome 2.X does?

Tags: unity, 11.04

Gnome 2.x always messes up my icons in the notification area and stuff when using dual monitor. I was wondering if the new unity will work better?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9886/how-does-unity-work-in-multi-monitor-configurations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As covered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9886/how-does-unity-work-in-multi-monitor-configurations), multi-monitor support for Unity in 11.04 is being treated with high importance.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're seeing with “messed up icons” is probably this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/44082

Yes, that will be fixed in Unity because it won't be using Gnome Panel. Instead, the bar at the top is more rigidly defined. Stuff that is meant to be at the right side will always be at the right side.

You will see this fixed in Gnome Shell, too, for the same reason.