# How does /will Unity handle multiple monitors?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Unity work in multi-monitor configurations?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9886/how-does-unity-work-in-multi-monitor-configurations)

Hi! What is planned for multiple monitor support in Unity? I can't seem to find a bug/blueprint anywhere, or a markup, or anything, actually. . . :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't link anything or cite any sources but I do know that it is in the planning to have the global menu appear on whatever monitor the active window resides in. This ingenuity reduces mouse movement quite a bit on the menus side.

Comment: This is intended to start appearing in 11.04 within the next week. (Source: [Unity lead developer on Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/njpatel/status/40185144782503936))