# How do I set-up three monitors with two graphics cards (3d acceleration enabled) in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, 11.10, multiple-monitors

I have looked at:

1. [How does /will Unity handle multiple monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27653/how-does-will-unity-handle-multiple-monitors) -> only two monitors with twinview
2. [How do I get three monitors working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21144/how-do-i-get-three-monitors-working) -> each monitor uses a separate x screen + xinerama (no 3d acceleration -> no Unity)

My current setup looks like this:

Two monitors in Twinview + one monitor as a separate X screen (it is not a problem that I cannot move windows from that monitor to the other two, I used to work like this on Ubuntu 10.10). The problem with this is, that I am unable to start applications on the separate X screen and when I manage to open a terminal on there, I am unable to interact with it (no window decoration).

I can still use my setup with the Gnome session (Ubuntu Classic), so I am not urgently looking for an answer, but I would like to know if it can be done and hopefully learn something in the process.

**Edit:** I should probably mention that I have two nvidia graphics cards in my computer. And that I am happy with the solution that I am currently using with gnome (i. e. TwinView + separate X screen). This won't work with Unity as I don't know of a way to launch applications on the separate X screen.

Comment: Unity is rough yet, and things like several X servers are beyond considerations now. May be it is time to try KDE? Plasma is not crashing now ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's currently quite hard to get even dual monitors working. There are reports of bugs and inability to get a dual monitor working so 3 monitors is going to be a stretch at this point.

Comment: I find it quite painless to use two (and even three) monitors with the nvidia drivers. I have added that information to my post.

Comment: Is it a reason not to do what you want?

Comment: Just saying it could be wise to wait a tad longer.

Comment: @ndefontenay When I read your reply, I misread it as a general response to the multi-monitor set-up. But I am still _hoping_ that there is a better answer than "Not Yet!" :-)

Comment: @bjoernz > Hi. I'm having the multi monitor issues (ie: Sitting idle) as well so I was looking around for how people experience it.

There's this guy who seems to succeed on more than 2 monitors.

I would suggest you try it first in a test environment. Because it seems to be working on a per user basis still.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7396/dual-monitor-support

Also the google search with more problems that solutions:
http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=unity+multi+monitor+setup&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: The first link should reply to your question: How unity handles it.

Comment: I have unchecked your answer, because it does not really explain how to set it up, only that it is impossible at the moment, and I agree with that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem for a very similar set up: 2 nvidia gpus, one using twinview and the other as a separate xscreen.  The separate xscreen is effectively useless with no keyboard input or menus...Maverick worked fine.

Guess we just wait...

EDIT filed bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/779124

Answer (score 1):

I get minor functionality by running a /usr/bin/unity link on my desktop in the seperate x-screens. I also created a new folder on the seperate desktops so I can get filesystem access. Still no panels, and due to unity, no menu bar, but at least it lets the keyboard work on the other screens.

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how to do that in your answer?