# Does Unity support Dual Monitors?

Tags: 11.04, unity, multiple-monitors

I just did a clean installation of Natty on my laptop, and I must say it is fantastic! I was apprehensive about Unity at first, but I have very quickly changed my mind.

Now with that said, my laptop is my testing machine, and my desktop is my super-stable-don't-change-anything machine. I'm impressed with the usability and stability of Unity on my laptop, but my desktop uses Dual monitors and I'm not sure how well that is supported at the moment.

Does anyone have any comments on using 11.04 with Dual monitors and how well it will work? First hand experiences or very recent links? All the research I have done on my own has only led to old (October) posts, and bug reports that appear to have been fixed so I would like to know from people who are actively running the final release of 11.04.

My graphics card is an nVidia GTX 460, which has been well supported on 10.04 and 10.10. Also my primary (slightly larger) monitor is to the right, but I'm not picky about which one I stare at.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9886/how-does-unity-work-in-multi-monitor-configurations

Comment: Thank you very much, but I had taken a look through that prior to posting this and that is why I specifically mentioned October in reference to old posts. this post seems outdated since it was written so long ago and I was curious about opinions from the final release and any updates made since then.

Comment: I've been updating that post since 11.04 was out, but I'll add more detail.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was unaware of that. I'll take a look at that then in a minute if you're currently editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have been running Ubuntu 11.04 on a brand new Lenovo Edge laptop for a few days now, and I am totally satisfied with everything except for dual monitor support.

It worked great yesterday when I first hooked up my second monitor, but today, after booting with the same monitor still connected, I ran into problems after opening both pidgin and Thunderbird.  The program panes would disappear when I tried to drag or re-size them and eventually I couldn't get them back even with the workspace switcher.  I played with dual monitor settings a bit, and then had both screens go left even when they had Normal selected.  This was easy enough to fix, but I actually had to unplug the second monitor on order to regain control of my program panes.

After arranging my panes to my liking, I plugged the second monitor back in and this time it was black except for the top status bar.  Back into the settings and things got worse.  I rebooted with the second monitor unplugged, and when I plugged it back in things were wonky again.  I'd really like to just reset the factory dual monitor configuration so I can get it working again like it was yesterday.  I think that if I boot with the factory configuration and then plug in the second monitor I should be fine, although that would be a slightly annoying workaround, and I can't see how to restore the factory dual monitor config.

Comment: You should post a question here asking about how to restore the default configuration. You should be able to find support for that.

Answer (score 2):

My only problem with dual monitors is that Unity wants them to both be the same size - and they're not. That screws up the top panel on the 2nd monitor, but other than that it seems to work pretty well. I'm hoping they fix it one day, but until then I'm still using it.

edit: Note: Using nvidia gear/drivers.